# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size' in loss function

Tags: function, pytorch, loss

**i am getting this error in train loop why? AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size' i am training a classifier. input is rgb and depth images**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-5158f610383b> in <module>
      9         optimizer.zero_grad()
     10         sal_output = backbone(sal_input)
---> 11         sal_loss_final = CE(sal_output, sal_label)
  

-> 2826     if not (target.size() == input.size()):
   2827         raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
   2828 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'
```

**here is my code**

````
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(backbone.parameters(), lr=0.00005, weight_decay=0.0005)
CE = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
for epoch in range(2):
    for i, data_batch in enumerate(train_loader):
        sal_image, sal_depth, sal_label = data_batch['sal_image'], 
               data_batch['sal_depth'],data_batch[
                    'sal_label']
        if (sal_image.size(2) != sal_label.size(2)) or (sal_image.size(3) != sal_label.size(3)):
                    print('IMAGE ERROR, PASSING```')
                    continue
        sal_input = torch.cat((sal_image, sal_depth), dim=0)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        sal_output = backbone(sal_input)
        sal_loss_final = CE(sal_output, sal_label)
        
        sal_loss_final.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        # print statistics
        running_loss += sal_loss_final.item()
        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
````

Comment: Either `sal_output` or `sal_label` is a python `list`. They should both be pytorch tensors.

Comment: How was `train_loader` defined? Can you show your dataset definition?

Comment: I have checked train_loader. sal_label is tensor. but sal_output is not tensor. I am new to pytorch kindly guide backbone() i defined is vgg16 model without linear layers.